# SQL - merge two database tables into one database table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I need to create a view (or a table) that holds n row values, taken from two different tables that have the same structure. For example:

table Country

```
id    name        Country
----------------------------
1     Franz       Germany
2     Alberto     Italy
3     Miguel      Spain
```

table email

```
id    name        Email
----------------------------
1     Franz       franz@gmail.com
2     Alberto     alberto@gmail.com
3     Miguel      miguel@gmail.com
```

table phoneno

```
id    name        Phone
----------------------------
1     Franz       111-111-1111
2     Alberto     111-111-1111
3     Miguel      111-111-1111
```

The merged database has to be like this:

```
id    name        Country        Email                 Phone
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Franz       Germany        franz@gmail.com       111-111-1111
2     Alberto     Italy          alberto@gmail.com     111-111-1111
3     Miguel      Spain          miguel@gmail.com      111-111-1111
```

Comment: why are you duplicating name data across all of these tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
Select 
Country.id,
Country.name,
Country.country,
email.Email,
phoneno.phone

FROM

Country
INNER JOIN email ON (Country.id = email.id)  
INNER JOIN phoneno ON (Country.id = phoneno.id)
```

Comment: does this make up a new table to query on? sorry new to sql so dont know much

Comment: No, it will fetch a result set that you want to see. It will not create any new table in database.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a table would duplicate the data; this would make sense only if you needed to create a snapshot of the data.
To always see the current state of the data, use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW Merged AS
SELECT c.id,
       c.name,
       c.Country,
       e.Email,
       p.Phone
FROM      Country AS c
LEFT JOIN email   AS e USING (id)
LEFT JOIN phoneno AS p USING (id);
```

Using an [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) will return rows even if some email or phone number is missing.
If there are multiple emails or phone numbers for one country row, you will get duplicate country data.

Comment: yes your right... it would help me alot if you would help me with the duplication of both table data into one.

Comment: Then edit the question to show relevant example data and the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

try selecting the required columns. You can fetch from multiple tables
like for example,

```
SELECT id, name, email, phone FROM table1, table2, table3
```

Comment: Without join conditions, you will end up with cartesian product with 3*3*3 rows. And id from which table? column ambiguity.